# How can I re-write this MATLAB code in a more idiomatic and efficient way?

Tags: matlab, refactoring

Here is the requirement: the input is a number which will divide an image into several equal part. For example, if the input is 4, it will return 3 parts: the values are the `imgSize/4` `imgSize/4 * 2` and `imgSize/4 * 3`.

If the input is `n`, then it will return `n - 1` elements, as in the following implementation:

```
if (colorLevel == 8)
    divide_thres = [ round(imgSize/8) round(imgSize/8)*2 round(imgSize/8)*3 round(imgSize/8)*4 
        round(imgSize/8)*5 round(imgSize/8)*6 round(imgSize/8)*7 ];
elseif (colorLevel == 4)
    divide_thres = [ round(imgSize/4) round(imgSize/4)*2 round(imgSize/4)*3 ];
elseif (colorLevel == 3)
    divide_thres = [ round(imgSize/3) round(imgSize/3)*2 ];
end
```

I want to allow the user to input a value between 2 and 255, and then automatically generate the `divide_thres` corresponding to that input. How can I re-write this code to be more efficient?

Comment: Your code only accommodates for `colorLevel = 3,4,8`, but your text says ` input a value from 2 to 255`? So what to do if user inputs a value other `3, 4, 8`?

Comment: Yes I want to accommodates every number ranging from 2 to 255, I only gave 3, 4, 8 as three examples.

Comment: Can user also input `n = 1`?If so, what must be the output?

Comment: `n = 1` should just return an error in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- In each case, you unnecessarily divide `imgSize` by the same factor multiple times (instead of just once and for all).
- You perform many "manual" scalar multiplications, but you could simply multiply the scalar value by a vector generated by the range `1 : colorLevel - 1`.
- Because the length of the resulting `divide_thres` vector can be easily computed from the value of `colorLevel`, there is no need to treat each case separately in an `if` statement.

  Moreover, even if you had to compute the length in a different manner for the cases `imgSize` = `3`, `4`, and `8`, you would be better off using a `switch` statement instead of an `if` statement, because the former would save you the trouble of writing `imgSize == ...` each time, which is prone to errors and a form of code duplication.

Here's a much simplified approach:

```
if 2 <= colorLevel && colorLevel <= 255
    divide_thres = round(imgSize / colorLevel) * (1 : colorLevel - 1);
else
    error('invalid colorLevel value') % (or some other informative message)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
divide_thres = [1:colorLevel-1]*round(imgSize/colorLevel)
```