# Looking for a more efficient way of writing my MATLAB code

Tags: matlab

I have written in MATLAB the following

```
for i = 1:3

   alpha11(i) = b+a.*randn(1,1);
   alpha22(i) = b+a.*randn(1,1);
   alpha12(i) = b+a.*randn(1,1);
   alpha21(i) = b+a.*randn(1,1);

AoD11(i) = randi([-180/6 +180/6],1,1);
AoA11(i) = randi([-180/6 +180/6 ],1,1);
AoD22(i) = randi([-180/6 +180/6],1,1);
AoA22(i) = randi([-180/6 +180/6 ],1,1);


AoD21(i) = randi([-180 +180],1,1);
AoA21(i) = randi([-180 +180 ],1,1);
AoD12(i) = randi([-180 +180],1,1);
AoA12(i) = randi([-180 +180 ],1,1);


 ctet11(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoD11(i));
 ctet22(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoD22(i));
 ctet12(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoD12(i));
 ctet21(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoD21(i));

 f_t11_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(M))*[ 1 exp(j*ctet11(i)) exp(j*2*ctet11(i)) exp(j*3*ctet11(i))  ]);
 f_t22_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(M))*[ 1 exp(j*ctet22(i)) exp(j*2*ctet22(i)) exp(j*3*ctet22(i))  ]);
 f_t12_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(M))*[ 1 exp(j*ctet12(i)) exp(j*2*ctet12(i)) exp(j*3*ctet12(i))  ]);
 f_t21_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(M))*[ 1 exp(j*ctet21(i)) exp(j*2*ctet21(i)) exp(j*3*ctet21(i))  ]);


 cter11(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoA11(i));
 cter22(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoA22(i));
 cter12(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoA12(i));
 cter21(i)= ((2*pi)/lambda)*d*sin(AoA21(i));

 f_r11_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(O))*[ 1 exp(j*cter11(i)) exp(j*2*cter11(i)) exp(j*3*cter11(i))  ]); 
 f_r22_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(O))*[ 1 exp(j*cter22(i)) exp(j*2*cter22(i)) exp(j*3*cter22(i))]); 
 f_r12_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(O))*[ 1 exp(j*cter12(i)) exp(j*2*cter12(i)) exp(j*3*cter12(i))  ]); 
 f_r21_ula{i}=transpose((1/sqrt(O))*[ 1 exp(j*cter21(i)) exp(j*2*cter21(i)) exp(j*3*cter21(i))]); 



 channel11{i}=  alpha11(i) * f_r11_ula{i}* conj(transpose(f_t11_ula{i})) ;
 channel22{i}= alpha22(i) * f_r22_ula{i}* conj(transpose(f_t22_ula{i})) ;
 channel12{i}= alpha12(i) * f_r12_ula{i}* conj(transpose(f_t12_ula{i})) ;
 channel21{i}= alpha21(i) * f_r21_ula{i}* conj(transpose(f_t21_ula{i})) ;

end
```

I am writing this question here to ask how I can compress this code, as you can see its not very nicely written and I have basically many repetitions. I don't know how to write them in few commands. Every command is repeated four times and indexed by 11, 12, 21, 22..

P.S If someone wants to run the code the following variables are needed

```
a = 1;
b = 0; 
M=4;
O = 4; 
lambda=0.15;
d=lambda/2;
```

Looking forward for suggestions.

Comment: You could probably replace each lot of `variable11(i)`, `variable12(i)`, `variable21(i)`, `variable22(i)` with `variable(:,:,i)` so you work with 3D arrays. Then you could replace the first 4 lines with `alpha(:,:,i)=b+a*randn(2,2)`. In fact, you might be able to avoid the `for` loop, you can make the final `alpha` using `alpha=b+a*randn(2,2,3)` (actually it might not be quite that simple for some of the operations you are doing).

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you suggesting that every variable I have above can be replaced by variable(:,:,i)?  is this the same i in the for loop? then how am I going distinguish between the four different cases?

Comment: `variable11(i)` will correspond to `variable(1,1,i)`, `variable21(i)` to `variable(2,1,i)`, etc. I think you should be able to so it for all the operations, it might be a little tricky, but you can always edit your question if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks, do I have to define the dimension of the variable before I use it in the for loop. I tried to write simply in the for loop alpha(:,:,i) =b+a rand(1,1).  I got the error Index exceeds matrix dimensions, if I try to compute alpha(2,1,3)

Comment: Do `rand(2,2)` instead

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651098/how-can-i-re-write-this-matlab-code-in-a-more-idiomatic-and-efficient-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David mentioned, it can be done using 3D arrays. This removes much of the code repetition.

Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
sz=[2,2,3];
alpha=b+a.*randn(sz);
AoD = randi([-180/6 +180/6],sz);
AoA = randi([-180 +180],sz);
mask = logical(repmat(eye(2),1,1,3));
[AoA(mask), AoD(~mask)] = deal(AoD(~mask),AoA(mask));
ctet = 2*pi/lambda * d * sin(AoD);
f_t = reshape(arrayfun(@(x) exp(1j*(0:3)'*ctet(x))/sqrt(M),1:12,'UniformOutput',0),sz);
cter = (2*pi)/lambda*d*sin(AoA);
f_r = reshape(arrayfun(@(x) exp(1j*(0:3)'*cter(x))/sqrt(O),1:12,'UniformOutput',0),sz);
channel = reshape(arrayfun(@(x) alpha(x) * f_r{x} * conj(transpose(f_t{x})), 1:12, 'UniformOutput',0),sz);
```

Note that for each of the variables mentioned in the question, the same values can be accessed using the corresponding 3D index. For example, using the code above, the value that was previously in `AoA11(1)` is now in AoA(1,1,1). Similarly, the matrix that was stored in `channel11{1}` is now in `channel{1,1,1}`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I receive an error when repmat is exectued and its as follows: Too many input arguments..Can you please give me more details.

Comment: That works in my version of matlab. If it's not working for you, try using the form that takes a vector of dimensions: mask = logical(repmat(eye(2), [1,1,3]));